# How do I close a modal window after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button which opens a  modal but I have prevented the modal close by clicking background or ESC key.

My button looks like this:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CompanyProfile"data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Click </button>
```

How do I close this modal after `$.ajax` success using jQuery?

**I have done a few tests - the modal has closed but the background gets locked, and I cannot do anything until I refresh the page**

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: button properties  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CompanyProfile"data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"

Comment: Can you post the modal as well and any associated css

Comment: Sir my ajax coding is working fine but i dont know how to close this modal becoz  button has these property 9data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To close bootstrap modal you can pass 'hide' as option to modal method as follows.

```
$('#CompanyProfile').modal('hide');
```

Use this code inside ajax success.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MGbXk/617/)

Comment: this one  is hide the modal but background is fadeout.. always i have refresh the page to continue

Comment: use `location.reload();` after hiding modal. This will automatically reload the page.

Comment: if you dont want to reload,use `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` to remove the backdrop. This is a not a proper way.

Comment: any other option with out reloading a page ? location.reload()

Comment: use $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

Comment: Rino Raj Thank you sooo much Sir... its working  Perfect .$("#CompanyProfile").hide(); $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); any short coding for this ?

Comment: Glad that helped. But it is not a good way. There might be some reason for that.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this lol how do i accept your answer ? pls tell me ?

Comment: i can see only two icons 1 Pencil icon (Edited) 2 Cross(Delete this comments) i dont see tick mark

Comment: Near my answer one grey tick mark is there. That one.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this solution since there doesn't seem to be a generic method listed.

If you wish to close any modal on success, but don't wish to hand-craft each $.ajax call to the server, you could use the following :

```
$('.modal form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serializeObject(),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.success);
            if(data.success===1) {
                // loop through all modal's and call the Bootstrap
                // modal jQuery extension's 'hide' method
                $('.modal').each(function(){
                    $(this).modal('hide');
                });
                console.log('success');
            } else {
                console.log('failure');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As an aside, if you are looking to use the code above as copy/paste, you will need the following which takes form data and converts it into JSON for posting to the server, or change the `$(this).serializeObject()` to `$(this).serialize()` :

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    o = { request: o };
    return o;
};
```

Reference: [Bootstrap JS Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {               
        $(".btn").button().click(function(){         // button click

                $('#CompanyProfile').modal('show')   // Modal launch
                     $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "url",
                              data:{data:data},
                              cache: false,                         
                              success: function(data) { 
                                                  $('.text').html(data); 
                                                 }
                   })                          
         });   
  });
```

Make sure the modal is launched only once

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. Untested but you'll get the idea.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourscript.php',
  data: $('form#yourForm').serialize(),
  type: 'post'
}).done(function(response) { 
  // trigger modal closing here since ajax is complete.
});
```

Comment: Since he said "after $.ajax success" shouldn't you be using `success` instead of `done`?

Comment: True, success can be used as well. (my habbit of using .done most of the times)

Comment: This don't solve the problem because he need exactly what you have in comment, how to trigger closing.

Comment: Yes Ben....  you correct but my problem is modal is not closing properly becoz button has these two properties (data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false") if i remove this property then everything work fine but user close this modal click by background or ECS button....

Answer (score 0):

I define my modal :

```
  <div class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" id="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="btnCloseModal" hidden type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong>Waiting</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div>
                    Please don't close your tab!
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <strong>Loading...</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then I use create function :

```
var StopLoadingAnimation = function () {
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("trigger show");
    $("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
});
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("trigger");
    $("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
});
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("event");
    $(e.currentTarget).off('shown');
    $(e.currentTarget).off('show');
});
$("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
```

}

My idea is after ajax success is will call function StopLoadingAnimation what will trigger event click on element btnCloseModal ( It like you click button btnCloseModal when you closing modal )

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#YourModalId').modal('toggle');` if you are targeting a modal inside (on top of) another modal.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button inside your modal, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" id="closemodal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
```

then, in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourcode.php",
  cache: false,
  data: dataString,
  success: function(html) {
    $('#closemodal').click ();
  }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

use **setTimeout**

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#CompanyProfile').modal('hide');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
success :function(){
              console.log("success");
              $('#contact_modal').html("<img src='img/bg/success.gif'>").delay(3000).fadeOut(450);
              $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
              $('.modal-backdrop.show').css('opacity','0');
              $('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index','-1')
          }
```