# Modal box does not close on successfull ajax return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that pops up whenever a screen is ideal for 3 minutes. It asks for a PIN to be entered and there is a Continue button on that to be clicked after the PIN is entered in it. On using this Continue button, an insert is made in a database table. Now my problem here is on entering the PIN and clicking on Continue button, the modal does not hides or closes itself. Although the database insertion is done but the modal does not hides. What can be possibly going wrong in this. Any suggestion will be highly helpful. My code,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->

<form name="frmActive" id="frmActive" action="" method="post">      
      <div class="modal-content" style="height:250px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Ideal Time activation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please enter activation <b>PIN</b><font color="red">*</font><br>

          <p id="msg" style="color:#F00;"></p>
          <input type="password" name="pin" id="pin" value="" maxlength="4"  onKeyUp="checkNumber(this)"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pin">
          <input type="hidden" id="inactiveTime">
          <p style="font-size:11px"><b><font color="red">*</font><font color="grey"><b>PIN</b><i> is mentioned in your welcome email.</font></i></b></p><br>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

       <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Continue</button> 
       <input type="hidden" id="module_id" value="<?php echo $moduleId ; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" id="chapter_id" value="<?php echo $chapterId ; ?>">

        </div>
      </div>
</form>      
   </div>
  </div>
jQuery("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){

    var pin             =   jQuery("#pin").val();
    var chapter_id      =   jQuery("#chapter_id").val();
    var module_id       =   jQuery("#module_id").val();
    var nowDate         =   jQuery.now();
    var inactiveTime    =   jQuery("#inactiveTime").val();
    var seconds         =   (nowDate - inactiveTime) / 1000;

    var formData    =   new FormData();
        formData.append("pin", pin);
        formData.append("seconds", seconds);
        formData.append("module_id", module_id);
        formData.append("chapter_id", chapter_id);

      $.ajax({
        url: "processActivation.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function(result){          


           if(result['status'] == 'active')

            {

                jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
            else
            {

                $("#msg").html(result) ;

            }

        }
      });

});
```

And processActivation.php,

```
<?php
$uid        =   $_SESSION['session_user_id'];
$dobCheck   =   $db->idToField("tbl_user", "dob", $uid);
$dob        =   explode("-", $dobCheck);

$pin            =   $_REQUEST['pin'];
$moduleId       =   $_REQUEST['module_id'];
$chapterId      =   $_REQUEST['chapter_id'];
$time_taken     =   $_REQUEST['seconds'];
$created        =   date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
if($pin != $dob[0])
{

    echo "Please enter valid PIN."; die;
}
else
{

    $dataactivation =   array("user_id"=>$uid, "module_id"=>$moduleId, "chapter_id"=>$chapterId,"time_taken"=>$time_taken, "created"=>$created);
    $db->query_insert("tbl_activation", $dataactivation);   


  header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200); 
  echo json_encode(array('status' => 'active')); 
  exit(); 
}

?>
```

I want to know if

```
header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200); 
      echo json_encode(array('status' => 'active')); 
      exit();
```

is the right way?? Because all of the above operations are being performed correctly and upon that `console.log(result)` does not shows up anything. Something wrong with the above couple of lines. Very helpful if somebody points out the error in this.

Comment: what issue you are getting

Comment: The modal box on successful PIN submission does not hides and stays . @GufranHasan

Comment: put console.log(result) and see response in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I close a modal window after AJAX success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773985/how-do-i-close-a-modal-window-after-ajax-success)

Comment: did the same.. It says , trim is not defined

Comment: I have updated my answer see that

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix maybe, instead of doing
`echo json_encode(array('status' => 'active'));` and `if(result['status'] == 'active')`
do
`echo "active";` and `if(result == 'active')`

Comment: Thanks for your time but no, this too does not works. Something else can be done??

Comment: I am sorry, but no success on this too. On console.log(result) I am getting ReferenceError: trim is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hide` function from jQuery.

```
jQuery('#myModal').hide();
```

As I know `modal('hide')` is used for bootstrap modals.

Comment: Thanks for the time. But I am sorry it does not works . The modal still stays. Can something else be done?

Comment: are you sure is the `#myModal` ?

Comment: Just updated my question for more clarity. Please take a look. @oma

Comment: `hide()` should work, please check your `result` and `result.['status']`

Comment: Maybe `status` is not ok, should be one of these: "success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"

Comment: So what can be altered in here.

Comment: change this line `if(result['status'] == 'active')` with `if(result['status'] == 'success')` and use the `hide()` form my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171460/discussion-between-ansh-and-oma).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery('#myModal').toggle().click();
```

instead of

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
```