# ajax call causing fits with hiding a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

EDIT: Found an un-elegant solution here:

[How do I close a modal window after AJAX success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773985/how-do-i-close-a-modal-window-after-ajax-success/35774042)

using location.reload(), though I have to say that I think there is a bug in the modal handling in jquery.  I do not think my code below was wrong yet it doesn't work. :(

When a user clicks a button it calls a method :

```
onClick(GroupInformationDialog(true)) ... etc
```

So that calls a method to see if we should hide or open a modal first based on what is passed and second based on what the result of another method that does an ajax call has:

```
function GroupInformationDialog(open) {
  if (open) {
    if (GetProviderInfo() == true) {
      $("#groupinfo-dialog").modal("show");
    } else {
      // we got no real data so let's not show the modal at all
      $("#groupinfo-dialog").modal("hide");
    }
  } else {
    $("groupinfo-dialog").modal("hide");
  }

  return false;
}
```

and the ajax call:

```
function GetProviderInfo() {
  event.preventDefault();
  gid = $('#group_info option:selected').val()
  pid = $("#provider_id").val()

  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'ipaswdb: get_group_info_data' %}',
    data: "group_id=" + gid + "&prov_id=" + pid,
    success: function (resp) {
      if (resp['response'] == 'NOGROUP') {
        alert("You must first select a group");
        $("groupinfo-dialog").modal('hide'); //arg this doesn't work either   
        return false;
      }
      else if (resp['response'] == 'OK') {
        //fill out form with data.
        $("#gi_date_joined_group").val(resp['date_joined_group']);// = resp['credentialing_contact'];
        $("#gi_provider_contact").val(resp['provider_contact']);
        $("#gi_credentialing_contact").val(resp['credentialing_contact']);
        return true;
      }
      else {
        $("#gi_date_joined_group").val('');// = resp['credentialing_contact'];
        $("#gi_provider_contact").val('');
        $("#gi_credentialing_contact").val('');
        return true;
      }

    }
  });
}
```

The problem is, the return true, or false in GetProviderInfo() is ignored, it is like GroupInformationDialog is evaluated all the way before GetProviderInfo is, so the result is a modal dialog that always pops up.

I even tried to have the

```
$("#groupinfo-dialog").modal('hide');
```

in the `if(resp['response']=='NOGROUP')` code section, with no dice.

It is almost like I need a wait function, I thought success was a call back function was going to take care of it, but alas it did not.

Comment: Please provide error free code: ```   event.preventDefault(); ``` - event is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing synchronous and async code here; you can't synchronously use `if (GetProviderInfo() == true)` since what you want to return from that function depends on an asynchronous ajax call.

The `return` statements you currenty have will go to the `success` handler they're contained within; they will *not* set the return value for `getProviderInfo` itself.  By the time that success handler runs, `getProviderInfo` has already returned.

You could have that function return a promise (using `return $.ajax({...})`) and have the caller handle the results asynchronously -- but it looks like in this case it might be simpler to just hide / show the modal from within the ajax call's `success` handler.   (It looks like the sole reason that isn't working currently is just a typo: there are a couple spots where you have `$("groupinfo-dialog")` when you mean `$("#groupinfo-dialog")`